# Why are Galerkin methods/FEMs used for solving PDEs and rather not ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have not yet understood Galerkin methods and in general not the structural differences between ODEs and PDEs (of course I know the basics but not why PDEs ist so much different except that they contain partial derivatives w.r.t. several variables). 
For instance, I don't understand why and what it means that ODEs can only be a finite-dimensional approximation of PDEs.

I guess, it is related that I don't understand why Galerkin methods or related methods are used for PDEs but never for ODEs (or are there any examples)?

Thanks in advance. I am very new to the theory of solving PDEs.

Comment: Galerkin-like methods are used for boundary value problems in ODE. Only there they are called "multiple shooting".

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a list of what I think that maybe could be relevant for you:

- [SUNA41, 1-D introduction to FEM](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/article/SUNA41.txt)
- [2-D Elementary Substructures](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2004/purified.pdf)
- [Circuits on an arbitrary triangular lattice](http://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Electric.html#Irregular)
- [Quadrilateral Algebra](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2004/vierhoek.pdf)
- [Resistor Models for Diffusion in 3-D](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/belgisch.pdf)

Background, philosophy and parent website:

- [The Manifesto](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/suna01.htm)
- [Unified Numerical Analysis](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather say initial value problems are numerically solved by time-stepping and boundary-value problems by Galerkin/FEM.
For example the transient dynamics of a mechanical structure, given by a PDE, is typically discretized in space by finite-elements and in time by time-stepping (e.g. Newmark). On the other hand a beam, string or some one-dimensional structure with BCs on both sides is described by an ODE and solved by FEM-like methods (BVP solvers, which are different from ODE solvers), whereas most ODEs have initial values, e.g. motion of a falling ball or a multibody-system.